# How to chain async actions redux saga (fetch of XHR requests)

Tags: asynchronous, redux, redux-saga

Is there some usual pattern to chain redux-saga async requests synchronously? Eg. 1 function loads user ID and the second call some API request using that ID. I will try to demonstrate (this code isn't solution, just demonstration)

```
function* laodUserSaga(action) {
  try {
    const res = yield apiGet('/user')
    const onboardingData = yield res.json()
    yield  put.resolve(loadUserSuccess(camelizeKeys(onboardingData)))
  } catch (error) {
    yield put.resolve(loadUserError(error))
  }
}
function* loadProfileDataByUserID(action) {
  const state = yield select();
  try {
    const res = yield apiGet(`/user/${state.userID}user-profile`)
    const onboardingData = yield res.json()
    yield  put.resolve(loadUserSuccess(camelizeKeys(onboardingData)))
  } catch (error) {
    yield put.resolve(loadUserError(error))
  }
}
function* loadProfileWithDataSaga(aciton){
  yield put(laodUserSaga)
  yield put(loadProfileDataByUserID)
}

function* sagaConnect() {
  yield all([
    takeLatest(LOAD_USER, laodUserSaga),
    takeLatest(LOAD_USER_DATA_BY_PROFILE_ID, loadProfileDataByUserID),
    takeLatest(LOAD_USER_WITH_PROFILE, loadProfileWithDataSaga),
  ])
}
```

you see, such examples would be really useful in docs of every library, 1 real world example is often what I understand in seconds, am I the only one?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to start every saga using takeEvery/Latest helper.

You can just call sagas as any other function, e.g.:

```
function* loadProfileWithDataSaga() {
  const user = yield call(loadUser)
  const profileData = yield call(loadProfileDataByUserID, user.id)
}
```

You just need to write `loadUser` and `loadProfileDataByUserID` sagas so that they receive and return the right values. If you want to be still able to call them in other scenarios by dispatching actions I would create another sagas that would just wrap the loadUser/Profile functionality.

Comment: Thank you, maybe this is more elegant solution than mine, I end up with writing separate saga for every page, it works as expected, but is deffinitely not DRY, I think, I can save some repetition writing at least loadUserData() your way